# Oracle calculate actual usage size and stats gathering

Tags: oracle

Each time an ETL job finished I have to collect the actual used space for each table (including its index spaces), as well as the row count.

The bytes column from user_segments and user_extents only indicates the space allocated. So I used the following to get each table size

```
  Dbms_Space.object_space_usage (
  object_owner    => v_owner,
  object_name     => c.name,
  object_type     => c.typ,
  sample_control  => NULL,
  space_used      => v_space_used_out,
  space_allocated => v_space_allocated_out,
  chain_pcent     => v_chain_pcent_out);
  v_space_used := v_space_used+v_space_used_out;
  v_space_allocated := v_space_allocated+v_space_allocated_out;
```

looping through each indexes and the table itself.

My question is before I run the above code is it necessary to run?

```
EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(v_owner,v_table_name);
```

Why and/or why no?

Thanks,

Comment: It seems like this would be pretty easy to test. Create a table, insert rows, run Dbms_Space.object_space_usage, and see what it tells you. Does that then change after you run gather_table_stats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not necessary to run EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(v_owner,v_table_name) ahead of running DBMS_SPACE.OBJECT_SPACE_USAGE

I ran  Dbms_Space.object_space_usage, got the results.  And then inserted a lot of data into a table, and ran  Dbms_Space.object_space_usage a second time.

The results were updated to the new, larger values, without running GATHER_TABLE_STATS.

We know from Oracle [DBMS_SPACE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_space.htm) documentation that this package requires the analyze privilege.  However, merely running OBJECT_SPACE_USAGE on a table, does not update the last_analyzed column of all_tables.

So from observation, DBMS_SPACE.OBJECT_SPACE_USAGE appears to do its own analysis of the table, getting correct space usage.  It does not rely on updated stats being collected by DBMS_STATS nor does it update the stats.

Just to further prove the point:

```
SQL> EXEC DBMS_STATS.delete_table_stats('SOMEOWNER','SOMETABLE');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


SELECT LAST_ANALYZED 
FROM ALL_TABLES 
WHERE OWNER = 'SOMEOWNER' AND TABLE_NAME = 'SOMETABLE';

LAST_ANALYZED
------------------


SQL> 
DECLARE
 su NUMBER;
 sa NUMBER;
 cp NUMBER;
BEGIN
  dbms_space.object_space_usage('SOMEOWNER', 'SOMETABLE', 'TABLE',
  NULL, su, sa, cp); 
  dbms_output.put_line('Space Used: ' || TO_CHAR(su));
  dbms_output.put_line('Space Allocated: ' || TO_CHAR(sa));
  dbms_output.put_line('Chained Percentage: ' || TO_CHAR(cp));
    END;
/

Space Used: 1055374677
Space Allocated: 1073741824
Chained Percentage: 0
```

Comment: Wonderful answer! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Based on the type of values returned, I'd guess that it is not accessing the table in order to do this analysis at all, it's simply reading the segment space management metadata for the table's segments. It would be interesting to see if this was so, by taking the table's tablespace offline and then running the DBMS_Space procedure.